# Como pegar a maior soma em um tabela?

Tags: mysql

tenho uma tabela

```
id  produto  vendas      data
 1  laranja     4     16-10-2016
 2  cenoura     3     16-10-2016
 3  cenoura     6     17-10-2016
 4  laranja     5     17-10-2016
 5  laranja     1     18-10-2016
 6  laranja     1     19-10-2016
```

a soma de laranjas da 11
a soma de cenoura da 9... Como eu faço pra a responta ser laranja 11(pega o item mais vendido e a soma)??

Answer (score 1):

Agrupando os resultados, mandando somar e pegando o primeiro item:

```
SELECT produto, SUM(vendas) AS total_vendas
FROM produtos
GROUP BY produto             -- agrupando pelo nome (o ideal seria id)
ORDER BY SUM(vendas) DESC    -- ordenando por soma, da maior para a menor
LIMIT 1;                     -- pegando apenas o primeiro resultado
```

[Veja funcionando no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ee35f/2)

Comment: Limit 1 seria para pegar somente o maior, se colocar 2 vai pegar os 2 maiores?

Comment: Sim. Se não colocar LIMIT pega todos, do mais vendido ao menos vendido.

Comment: Mas com isso e não consigo saber qual é o produto que mais vendeu.

Comment: para mim aqui só aparece a soma do produto mais vendido, mas não diz qual produto é

Comment: Tem de ter `produto` no select, como no meu exemplo, logo no início

Comment: @DanEven Coloquei um link para um exemplo funcional para você ver, com o LIMIT comentado.